# "Next" button on Android Numeric keypad

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova

I am wondering about how to detect "Next" button event on android numeric keypad using Jquery. Please give me solution how to trigger that button event.

Comment: Bind focusout. Read http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar i am not getting what you are saying,can you give me clear example?

Answer (score 7):

You can detect the `next` keyboard press by using the following bind in JQuery:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 9) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

The 'next' button emulates the `tab` keypress event on a keyboard, which is key code 9. Unfortunately, keypress and keyup events do not detect the `next` key event, so you need to bind it on `keydown`.

Comment: On my environment (Android 4.2.x, Samsung S4), it works like a charm, but only with `e.which == 9`, not with `===`.