# How to detect pressing NEXT on numeric keypad using jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I would like to detect if user has pressed "NEXT" button of numeric keypad (using jquery). So far I have tried keypress, keyup as well as keydown events but it is not getting detected.

Is there a way to detect it?

Comment: I know that there are ways to do that with a JAVA plugin.  I will look at bit more into it, but you can also check this out:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/PoVFIJ9F2OA

Answer (score 0):

Try this from a earlier question from Stackoverflow:

["Next" button on Android Numeric keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724014/next-button-on-android-numeric-keypad)

**Oh shoot, i mixed 2 question up**

Im going to let this stay though, use it to get further.

Simon Mac Donald made a post about invoking functionalites to the back button

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.dk/2011/05/overriding-back-button-in-phonegap.html

Basicly this is it.  Read the above guide still :)

```
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);
```

I just tested it, it works.

Just remember to click one of the div links.  An eventlistener is hooked to it.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Next and Back are two different things. Back is the hardware button and can easily be caught/overwritten...

The Next key on the numerical SoftKeyboard seems to be buggy. Theoretically you should be able to catch it using this simple jquery:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){

        if(e.which === 9) 
        {
            // your code
        }
    });
```

But somehow, as of API 17 and 18, it is not. I can catch all the events of the keyboard except the Next key. So this seems to be a bug on the numerical softKeyboard.

This issue has been entered as a bug in Chrome but I suspect it to be the actual numerical Keyboard to be buggy:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142233